# How to use acceleration to move an object in 2D game for android in unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I've tried this code but it doesn't work properly:

```
public void carSpeed = 10.0f;
void Update() {
    Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;
    dir.x = -Input.acceleration.y;
    dir.z = Input.acceleration.x;
    if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1)
        dir.Normalize();

    dir *= Time.deltaTime;

    Vector3 position = transform.position += (dir * carSpeed);
    position.x = Mathf.Clamp(position.x, -2.7f, 2.7f);
    transform.position = position;
}
```

Comment: Add some detail. What happens? (side note, but you should probably fix that formatting a little)

Comment: Actually i'm developing a 2D racing game. I use the following code to move my car and it works fine. But now i want to move my car by tilting my phone not using touch.

Comment: `void Update() {
  if (Input.touchCount == 1) {
   Touch touch = Input.touches [0];
   if (touch.position.x < Screen.width / 2) {
   transform.position += Vector3.left * carSpeed * Time.deltaTime; 
   } 
  else if (touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2) {
   transform.position += Vector3.right * carSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
   }
   Vector3 position = transform.position;
   position.x = Mathf.Clamp (position.x, -2.7f, 2.7f);
   transform.position = position;
  }
 }`

Comment: Consider using Vector2 instead of Vector3, since you're not using depth.

Comment: I was trying to use Vector 2 variable instead of Vector3 but the compiler shows up an error. :( The error message is look like this...   Assets/Scripts/carController.cs(26,46): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `UnityEngine.Vector2.operator +(UnityEngine.Vector2, UnityEngine.Vector2)' and `UnityEngine.Vector3.operator +(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)'